# Customs UIView's in TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've some difficulties to understand how this `UIViewController` is made. I think a scheme of the `UIView`'s used in this `UIViewController` will help me to understand

Here is the  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqzP6.png) of the `UIViewController`

I want to make something like that : put an `UIView` with `UILabel`, `UIImageView`, `UITextField`,... inside a `TableView`, between two cells.

Comment: Please also upload some sample code of what you are trying to achieve when you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UITableViewController` with static cells for this layout scheme and perform this layout directly from storyboard. 
Alternatively you can put custom views inside vertical stack view and put it all into scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put normal views between cells. You can use various types of custom cells to get the look you want, but a table view manages its view hierarchy and you absolutely cannot add your own views to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own customised tableHeaderFooterView and cells. Then you will only need to register them to the tableView and do logic on the cellForRowAt and headerFooterViewInSection methods.